# How to click on the element in div, span

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Below is my script and the html. I am not able to click on the dropdown menu, and then select "twelve" from the list. I have tried with xpath, name, but nothing seems to work. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

my script:

```
WebElement temp = driver.finaElement(By.cssSelector("#s2id_campaignStatus > a.select2-choice > span"));
temp.click();
```

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <div class="select2-container select2-container-active" id="s2id_campaignStatus">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="return false;" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1">                                                  
                        <span>twelve</span>
                            <abbr class="select2-search-choice-close" style="display:none;"></abbr>
                            <div>
                                <b></b></div>
                                </a><input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text"></div>
                                <select name="campaignStatus" id="campaignStatus" class="select2-offscreen" tabindex="-1">


                                <option value="W" selected="selected">ABC</option>

                                            <option value="L">one</option>
                                            <option value="P">two</option>
                                            <option value="O">three</option>
                                            <option value="C">four</option>
                                            <option value="R">five</option>
                                            <option value="J">six</option>
                                            <option value="X">seven</option>
                                            <option value="S">eight</option>
                                            <option value="A">nine</option>
                                            <option value="D">ten</option>
                                            <option value="T">twelve</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding-left:12px;">
                            <a href="#" onclick="showTemplate()">
                                What is a Template?
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody></table>
```

my test Code @Saifur:

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("campaignStatus"))).selectByValue("T");

        By elementId = By.id("campaignStatus");
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 8);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(elementId));
        new Select(driver.findElement(elementId)).selectByValue("T");
```

Comment: Please make sure you add related tags and exceptions

Answer (score 0):

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("campaignStatus"))).selectByVisibleText("twelve");
```

You also have multiple options using `Select` class. See [this](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html)

```
new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("campaignStatus"))).selectByValue("T");
```

**EDIT add wait for the element to be ready state**

```
By elementId = By.id("campaignStatus");
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(elementId );
new Select(driver.findElement(elementId)).selectByValue("T");
```

Comment: Is the element visible?

Comment: Is the `select` element not visible itself? If so you have to make that visible by some other action. If that is visible but there is some element wait issue use the edited code

Comment: I get this error:        org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"campaignStatus"}
@Saifur

Comment: Any Iframe involved on that page?

Comment: There are iframe on the page, but div is not in that iframe

Comment: As I said earlier you have to make sure the element is visible first. `NoSuchElementException` means selenium could not find the element you are looking for. Probably frame, or selector issue. Can you provide little more of the test codes you are using?

Comment: On above pasted code you don't need `new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("campaignStatus"))).selectByValue("T");` And, are you sure that `div` is not inside the Iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code, It should work for you

*I have given Manual wait of 2 sec before and after selecting '**twelve**' from the Drop-down list.*

***Explicit wait*** time of 8 sec to  wait till select element gets Click-able.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 8);
WebElement Manages = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//select[@id='campaignStatus']")));
Select dropDownelement = new Select(Manages);
Thread.sleep(2000);
dropDownelement.selectByVisibleText("twelve");
Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Comment: I get this error:               org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 8 seconds waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //select[@id='campaignStatus']
@Rupesh Shinde